# Inline linear-gradient on a background Image

Tags: css, reactjs, inline

I have an image with a slight black linear gradient over it to improve readablitiy

```
.hero-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("./images/slideshow/2.jpg");
```

However I am using a slideshow that only accepts divs with inline `backgroundImage` properties

```
<div
          className="slideshow-image"
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slideshow2})`, repeat: "no-repeat" }}
        >
```

The trouble is I cannot add the linear gradient that the image had before with inline styling.

```
//attempt 1
const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${slideshow1})`,
    linearGradient: "(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5))",
  };
```

```
// attempt 2 
style={{
            linearGradient: "(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5))",
            backgroundImage: `url(${slideshow1})`,
            repeat: "no-repeat",
          }}
```

```
//attempt 3 
.slideshow-image {
 
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
```

Neither of these display anything over the image. What can I try next to accomplish this?

Comment: did you consider CSS variables? ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68185321/8620333

Comment: I tried that answer by adding `.slideshow-image::before {
  
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, green);
  
}` But it still doesn't show anything on the image

Comment: no, you don't have to add pseudo element, that answer is to show you the CSS variable technique. You need to make the image url a variable that you can change inline

Comment: I don't understand, the imageUrl is already a variable ``url(${slideshow1})``

Comment: I am talking about CSS variable

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use a css variable while also using the inline background image

Answer (score 0):

You can also override an inline CSS style using `!important` in your CSS.

Your CSS will become

```css
.slideshow-image{
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
```

and your markup could be changed slightly

```
<div
          className="slideshow-image"
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slideshow2})`}}
        >
```